# Creating a column chart with a variable number of Y values

Tags: .net, charts

I am using the asp.net chart control and have searched but have been unable to find a solution to create a chart similar to the following (apologies for the ascii).

```
|
|             +-+
|             | |         +-+
| +-+         | |     +-+ | |
| | | +-+     | |     | | | | +-+
| | | | |     | |     | | | | | |
+---------|---------|------------
    A          B          C
```

The issue is that all solutions appear to assume a common number of Y series across all X values.

I should add that my data is similar to this:

```
MAKE  | MODEL | RATING
---------------------
FORD  | COUPE | 4.5
FORD  | WAGON | 3.5
CHEVY | HATCH | 2.5
CHRY  | VAN   | 4.5
CHRY  | SEDAN | 5.5
CHRY  | COUPE | 4.5
```

The MAKE would be the X series and the MODEL/RATING would be the Y series within the X series.

Does anyone have a solution for this sort of chart?

Answer (score 0):

.NET has a pretty nice set of charting controls.  I've used them.  It can handle bar charts like this.

[Download them here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14422) or Google for Microsoft Chart Controls

Comment: As I said in the description I am already using the asp.net chart control.  It is the this type of chart that I'm trying to create with the control already.

Comment: Sorry, I read right past that.  My bad.  However, wouldn't it be three `ChartArea`s side by side?  (Forgive me; it's been over a year since I've used them.)

Comment: Hm, I hadn't considered multiple ChartArea's.  I've been trying to create a single ChartArea with a variable # of Series.  That will change my Google-Fu so that's something to go on.  Thanks, I'll check it out.

Comment: Quickly, it looks like multiple chart areas will create multiple charts that don't necessarily combine into one seamless looking chart, which is not exactly what I need.

Comment: It might take some work but I think you can align them, get rid of superfluous axes, etc., so they behave as one chart.  It's not automatic out of the box, I agree.